# Single word for something that is harmful, yet necessary

Tags: single-word-requests

Can anyone please help me to substitute "something that harms us, but we which also we depend on" with an equivalent word or phrase?

An example: "Every year, river water causes flooding in its vicinity, but the people living nearby are continuously dependent on the river to make their living".

Comment: I don’t see why this has two “Primarily Opinion-Based” close votes. If there is a word that describes something that is necessary or upon which we depend, but which is also harmful to us, then this is a perfectly fine SWR question, as far as I can see.

Comment: This question has been asked in many forms. Searching for *necessary evil* will yield many results, all imperfect (so I've not CV as a dupe). However, *necessary evil* is the most common phrase to describe this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a word to describe something that is bad/harmful, yet needed/imperative?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166004/is-there-a-word-to-describe-something-that-is-bad-harmful-yet-needed-imperative)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would call that "a necessary evil."
In some cases, it may also be an [addiction](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addiction).

Answer (score -1):

burdensome, onerous (adj.)--having obligations (e.g. legal obligations) that outweigh the advantages.