# Necessary, but it shouldn't have to be - in a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes something as being necessary, but it shouldn't have to be (if you follow). Example: Door locks are necessary, but if members of society had more trust and there were no burglars, there would be no necessity. Environmental NGOs are necessary, but if there was no pollution there would be no necessity.
Any thoughts for a word defined as "necessary but shouldn't be"?
[Edit in response to a comment] Sample context: Given that the Center for Humane Technology's mission is to support "our well-being, democracy, and shared information environment", it would be redundant if Big Tech and its subscribers and users behaved better.
"*The CHT is xxxxx*" (necessary, but should not have to be).

Comment: The usual two-word expression (though CD labels it a compound) is **necessary evil**. From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/necessary-evil): << _necessary evil_
 ... something unpleasant that must be accepted in order to achieve a particular result:
_● I think he regards work as a necessary evil.
● Most Americans accept taxes as a necessary evil._ >> // Related:  [a word for something that is bad/harmful yet needed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166004/is-there-a-word-to-describe-something-that-is-bad-harmful-yet-needed-imperative)

Comment: compulsory, forced, imperative, incumbent, involuntary, mandatory, nonelective, obligatory, peremptory, required,... If something is ***obligatory***, there's really not much point in discussing whether it's "desirable" or not. ***We are where we are.***

Comment: Thanks @KillingTime. I have edited post to illustrate this.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers - Very good point. Given the reality of the situation, something becomes necessary because of the factors that brought it into existence. I suppose what I am looking for is a word to categorise such a situation, not just to give it a descriptive adjective.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth - This time with a little more care and attention: I don't want to imply that the thing that should not be necessary is undesirable. If you have time, please see my edit to the original post.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the recent edit justifies my "re-open" vote, but it occurs to me that *should not be necessary* implies that there's ***some specific factor*** causing the necessity (i.e. - if that factor didn't apply, nor would the necessity). So although it's not actually a single-word term, [***concomitant necessity***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22concomitant+necessity%22) may have the required connotations. (Such a "necessity" isn't necessarily highly undesirable, unless you just really hate not having any choice in the matter! :)

Comment: I love such questions. Makes me want to think of new words to add to the English language.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it meets your requirements specifically, but in your example I would use the word superfluous.

*Superfluous: unnecessary, especially through being more than enough.*

> Given that the Center for Humane Technology's mission is to support
> "our well-being, democracy, and shared information environment", it
> would be redundant if Big Tech and its subscribers and users behaved
> better. The CHT is superfluous.

Superfluous doesn't mean "required" however, it just means present.